# Javascript merge an object and an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

My problem is to merge an object and an array of objects.

Here's my object:

```
{

  model1: ["model1-coupe", "model1-hatchback", "model1-cabriolet"],
  model2: ["model2-coupe","model12-hatchback","model2-cabriolet"],
  model3: ["model3-coupe","model4-hatchback","model4-cabriolet"]

}
```

Here's my array of objects:

```
[
    {image: "/path/to/image/model1.jpg"},
    {image: "/path/to/image/model2.jpg"},
    {image: "/path/to/image/model3.jpg"}
]
```

I'd like to merged them like that:

```
[
    {
        image: "/path/to/image/model1.jpg",
        model1: ["model1-coupe", "model1-hatchback", "model1-cabriolet"]
    },

    {
        image: "/path/to/image/model2.jpg",
        model2: ["model2-coupe", "model2-hatchback", "model2-cabriolet"]
    },

    {
        image: "/path/to/image/model3.jpg",
        model3: ["model3-coupe", "model3-hatchback", "model3-cabriolet"]
    }
]
```

How do I do that? I can use either JavaScript or Underscore.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT: see how the merging result would actually be:**

```
[
    {
        image: "/path/to/image/model1.jpg",
        cars: ["model1-coupe", "model1-hatchback", "model1-cabriolet"]
    },

    {
        image: "/path/to/image/model2.jpg",
        cars: ["model2-coupe", "model2-hatchback", "model2-cabriolet"]
    },

    {
        image: "/path/to/image/model3.jpg",
        cars: ["model3-coupe", "model3-hatchback", "model3-cabriolet"]
    }
]
```

Comment: What relates the model to the image? Is there always a model for an image, only one image and not more than one and are they always in the same order?

Comment: There's always an image for a model and they are spit out from the services in the same order

Comment: You shouldn't rely on ordering to match up models and images, since ordering of object properties isn't specified by the standard (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.6.4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0, key; i < modelArray.length; i++) {
    modelArray[i].cars = modelObject[Object.keys(modelObject)[i]];
}
```

This will loop the array and add the property to the object. This assumes that the object properties are all in the proper order.

In each iteration, it loops up which property it's up to using `Object.keys()`. Then, it sets that key of the object in the array to that property of the model object.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```js
var models = {

  model1: ["model1-coupe", "model1-hatchback", "model1-cabriolet"],
  model2: ["model2-coupe", "model12-hatchback", "model2-cabriolet"],
  model3: ["model3-coupe", "model4-hatchback", "model4-cabriolet"]

}


var images = [{
  image: "/path/to/image/model1.jpg"
}, {
  image: "/path/to/image/model2.jpg"
}, {
  image: "/path/to/image/model3.jpg"
}]


for (var key in models) {
  if (models.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var idx = +key.match(/\d+$/)[0] - 1;
    images[idx][key] = models[key]
  }
}

console.log(images)
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
var result = [];

var models = {
    // your models object
}
var images = [
    // your images array
];

for(var i=0, key in models) {
    var model = models[key];
    var image = images[i++]; 
    result.push( { image: image, model: model } );
}
```